# How to check which version of R a package supports

Tags: r

I have tried to install the R package swiRcharts and received the following message:

> package ‘swiRcharts’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

Where in the package files (available on GitHub) on from R console can I check which version of R the package was made for?

Comment: I think the package is made for an older version. I have installed R 3.3.1 which should be the latest

Comment: The minimum required is frequently in the DESCRIPTION file under "Depends", but doesn't appear to be in this case. You could check those of the package dependencies listed, though, which may.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire I have checked the dependencies and most of the define the R version as greater than some version. I didn't find any that defines less than some version. I am really curious now to find out how this works...

Comment: Wait, when are you getting that message? If you're using `install.packages`, I think it's telling you it's not on CRAN. You could probably use `devtools::install_github`.

Comment: @alistaire you are right! devtools::install_github worked fine. The console message mislead me.

Comment: Glad it worked! If you're using RStudio, if you use the button on the "Packages" pane to install, the autocomplete will give you a good idea if the package exists on CRAN or not. Sometimes there's a little difference between mirrors, depending on when each last updated.